# docker Failed to create the host-only adapter Windows 7

Tags: docker, installation, windows-7-x64

I am trying to install/run docker.

When running the docker quickstart terminal I run into the following error message:

```
Machine default already exists in VirtualBox.
Starting machine default...
Error setting up host only network on machine start: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe hostonlyif create failed:
0%...
Progress state: E_FAIL
VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not find Host Interface Networking driver! Please reinstall
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "enum RTEXITCODE __cdecl handleCreate(struct HandlerArg *)" at line 71 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
Looks like something went wrong... Press any key to continue...
```

The closest thing I could find on the network related to antivirus problems. I have Symantec Endpoint Protection, which I cannot disable. So hopefully you could provide some ideas that don't touch this :)

Otherwise I can create a VM that is working using an ubuntu ISO.

docker-machine version: 0.5.4, build 6643d0e and seems to be working.

curl is working and I files downloaded, i.e. the internet connection cannot be the problem...

I don't know what to do and where to look...

Thx for any suggestions.

Bernd

Answer (score 4):

I have run into this issue several times on different Microsoft OS's when VirtualBox pushes out an update. (just happened today 7-20-2017)

A quick fix is as follows:

**Step 1**

a.  Go into the VirturalBox Host-Only Network adapter properties in Windows

b.  Un-check the VirtualBox NDIS6 Bridged Networking Driver

c.  Click "OK" to save the settings

**Step 2**

a.  Go into VirtualBox, and start the VM you are haivng issues with.

b.  Once booted, shutdown the VM

**Step 3**

a.  Go back into the VirturalBox Host-Only Network adapter properties in Windows

b.  Re-check the VirtualBox NDIS6 Bridged Networking Driver

c.  Click "OK" to save the settings

After this, the VM you are having issues with should launch successfully and function as intended.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and did the following steps:

1. Downloaded the version of Vbox to the latest one. (5.2.. -> 6.0..)
2. Opened the docker terminal as administrator.

For many step 2 might work in the first go.